# solving polynomials

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Given any three distinct non-collinear points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3) ∈ R^2$, we can define for $i = 1,2,3$,

$f_i (x,y)=∏_{1≤j≤3,j≠i}(x-x_j)+∏_{1≤j≤3,j≠i}(y-y_j)$

and if $f_i(x_i, y_i)≠0$ for  $i = 1, 2, 3$, we can define $k_i$  such that $k_if_i(x_i, y_i) = 1$ for  $i = 1,2,3$. Using the above notations, find the  $G(x,y$) of the form of $x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F$ such that $G(x_1,y_1)=G(x_2,y_2)=G(x_3,y_3)=0$.

I know that $f_i(x_j,y_j)=0$ for $j≠i$, but how can I relate this to $G(x, y)$?

Comment: My edit  added all the missing dollar signs and  I fixed the subscript/superscript notation. I removed a few words in the middle that seemed unnecessary.For a group of characters e.g. $1\leq j\leq 3, j\ne i$ in a subscript,surround them with {  }, not  with (   ).

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer.Let $g=k_1f_1+k_2f_2+k_3f_3-1$. We have $g(x_i,y_i)=0$ for $i=1,2,3.$ If $ c=k_1+k_2+k_3\ne 0$ we can let $G=g/c$. If $c=0$, I will have to think about it.